# Use Cefnet in avalonia

Tags: c#, .net, chromium-embedded, avalonia

I;m trying to setup Cefnet in my avalonia application. My program.cs looks like this:

```
internal class Program
{
    // Initialization code. Don't use any Avalonia, third-party APIs or any
    // SynchronizationContext-reliant code before AppMain is called: things aren't initialized
    // yet and stuff might break.
    [STAThread]
    public  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var webRootPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "webcomponents");
        var server = new WebServer("http://localhost:2005");
        server.WithStaticFolder("/", webRootPath, false);
        server.RunAsync();
        //initialize cefnet
        var settings = new CefSettings();
        settings.NoSandbox = true;
        settings.MultiThreadedMessageLoop = false; // or true
        settings.WindowlessRenderingEnabled = true;
        settings.LocalesDirPath = "C:\\Users\\noble\\Downloads\\cef_binary_105.3.39+g2ec21f9+chromium-105.0.5195.127_windows64\\cef_binary_105.3.39+g2ec21f9+chromium-105.0.5195.127_windows64\\Resources\\locales";
        settings.ResourcesDirPath = "C:\\Users\\noble\\Downloads\\cef_binary_105.3.39+g2ec21f9+chromium-105.0.5195.127_windows64\\cef_binary_105.3.39+g2ec21f9+chromium-105.0.5195.127_windows64\\Resources";

        var app = new CefNetApplication();
        app.Initialize("C:\\Users\\noble\\Downloads\\cef_binary_105.3.39+g2ec21f9+chromium-105.0.5195.127_windows64\\cef_binary_105.3.39+g2ec21f9+chromium-105.0.5195.127_windows64\\Release", settings);
        BuildAvaloniaApp()
        .StartWithClassicDesktopLifetime(args);
       
    }


    // Avalonia configuration, don't remove; also used by visual designer.
    public static AppBuilder BuildAvaloniaApp()
        => AppBuilder.Configure<App>()
            .UsePlatformDetect()
            .LogToTrace()
            .UseReactiveUI();
}
```

When i try to debug the program, the program doesent start. I get this in the debug console:

```
The program '[20424] Dynamo Desktop.exe' has exited with code 2147483651 (0x80000003).
```

There are no other errors or exceptions,
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This is a native crash, you can collect crashes here %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\CrashDumps, then download the debug symbols from here https://cef-builds.spotifycdn.com/index.html and debug the minidump file. Did you consider using OutSystem's WebView (also, CEF-based) or DotNetBrowser (Chromium-based)?

Comment: Did you try initializing cefnet BEFORE `WebServer`?